# InvalidOperationException when using SavePictureToCameraRoll of MediaLibrary

Tags: windows-phone-7

I get an exception trying to save a picture on a `CameraCaptureTask` callback. Why is that ? I'm debugging through `WPConnect.exe`, and I do have to capability `ID_CAP_MEDIALIB`.

```
void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        string fileName = adViewModel.Id + DateTime.Now.Ticks + ".jpg";
        using (IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {
            if (myIsolatedStorage.FileExists(fileName))
            {
                myIsolatedStorage.DeleteFile(fileName);
            }

            IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.CreateFile(fileName);
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage();
            bitmap.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

            WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap(bitmap);
            wb.SaveJpeg(fileStream, wb.PixelWidth, wb.PixelHeight, 0, 85);
            fileStream.Close();

            fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();

            // this line throw the exception
            Picture pic = library.SavePictureToCameraRoll(fileName, fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding the `ID_CAP_CAMERA` capability as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.savepicture.aspx) SavePicture will throw an exception if the phone is tethered to the computer. I imagine SavePictureToCameraRoll will be the same.